# Matlab: Finding two unknown constants/parameters in an equation

Tags: matlab, parameters

I've read up on fsolve and solve, and tried various methods of curve fitting/regression but I feel I need a bit of guidance here before I spend more time trying to make something work that might be the wrong approach.

I have a series of equations I am trying to fit to a data set (x) separately:

for example:

> ```
> (a+b*c)*d = x
> a*(1+b*c)*d = x
> ```
>
> x = 1.9248
>       3.0137
>       4.0855
>       5.0097
>       5.7226
>       6.2064
>       6.4655
>       6.5108
>       6.3543
>       6.0065
>
> c=  0.0200
>       0.2200
>       0.4200
>       0.6200
>       0.8200
>       1.0200
>       1.2200
>       1.4200
>       1.6200
>       1.8200
>
> d = 1.2849
>       2.2245
>       3.6431
>       5.6553
>       8.3327
>      11.6542
>      15.4421
>      19.2852
>      22.4525
>      23.8003

I know c, d and x - they are observations. My unknowns are a and b, and should be constant.

I could do it manually for each x observation but there must be an automatic and far superior way or at least another approach.

Very grateful if I could receive some guidance. Thanks for the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your two example equations; let y=x./d, then

- y = a+b*c
- y = a+a*b*c

The first case is just a line, for which you can obtain a least squares fit (values for `a` and `b`) with `polyfit()`. In the second case, you can just say k=a*b (since these are both fitted anyway), then rewrite it as:

- y = a+k*c

Which is exactly the same line as the first problem, except now b = k/a. In fact, b=b1/a is the solution to the second problem where b1 is the fit from the first problem. In short, to solve them both, you need one call to `polyfit()` and a couple of divisions.

Will that work for you?

Comment: Thank you! I will read up about polyfit. This solution along with Prashant seems the most sensible.

Answer (score 1):

I see two different equations to fit here. To spell out the code:

For `(a+b*c)*d = x`

```
p = polyfit(c, x./d, 1);
a = p(2);
b = p(1);
```

For `a*(1+b*c)*d = x`

```
p = polyfit(c, x./d, 1);
a = p(2);
b = p(1) / a;
```

Comment: Thank you! I should read up on polyfit and establish when to use it and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `polyfit`; this is just a linear least squares problem, which is best solved with MATLAB's [`slash`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) operator:

```
>> ab = [ones(size(c)) c] \ (x./d)
ans =
   1.411437211703194e+000  % 'a'
  -7.329687661579296e-001  % 'b'
```

Faster, cleaner, more educative :)

And, as Emmet already said, your second equation is nothing more than a different form of your first equation, the difference being that the `b` in your first equation, is equal to `a*b` in your second one.